# JavaScript+iMacros if-else

Tags: firefox, csv, macros, imacros

I have some problems with iMacros in Firefox.

This is my macros "test.js":

```
var macros;
var macrosrun;
var s_n = "\n";
var getExtract;
var i;

for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    macros = "CODE:";
    macros += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+s_n;
    macros += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO"+s_n;
    macros += "SET !DATASOURCE test\.csv"+s_n;
    macros += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE "+i+s_n;
    macros += "SET !VAR1 {{!COL8}}"+s_n;
    macros += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}"+s_n;
    getExtract = iimGetExtract(1);
    iimDisplay(getExtract);
    if (getExtract == 1) {
        macros += "URL GOTO={{!COL5}}"+s_n;
    } else if (getExtract == 2) {
        macros += "URL GOTO={{!COL6}}"+s_n;
    } else if (getExtract == 3) {
        macros += "URL GOTO={{!COL7}}"+s_n;
    }
    macros += "WAIT SECONDS=1"+s_n;
    macrosrun = iimPlay(macros);
}
```

And this is "test.csv"

```
1,"test","test",12345,"http://twitter.com","http://facebook.com","http://google.com",1,"Test 1"
2,"test","test",12345,"http://twitter.com","http://facebook.com","http://google.com",2,"Test 2"
3,"test","test",12345,"http://twitter.com","http://facebook.com","http://google.com",3,"Test 3"
```

I think, if "1" in first string in column8, macros'll go to "twitter.com"
if "2" - "facebook.com", and if "3" - "google.com"

But in real macros run 3 - 1 - 2... not 1 - 2 - 3... why?)

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call iimPlay before calling getLastExtract you will pull the proper values from the datasource.

Here is your example with a few modifications:

```
var macros;
var macrosrun;
var s_n = "\n";
var getExtract;
var i;
var col5, col6, col7;

for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    macros = "CODE:";
    macros += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES"+s_n;
    macros += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO"+s_n;
    macros += "SET !DATASOURCE test\.csv"+s_n;
    macros += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE " + i + s_n;
    macros += "SET !VAR1 {{!COL8}}"+s_n;
    macros += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}"+s_n;
    macros += "SET !VAR1 {{!COL5}}"+s_n;
    macros += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}"+s_n;
    macros += "SET !VAR1 {{!COL6}}"+s_n;
    macros += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}"+s_n;
    macros += "SET !VAR1 {{!COL7}}"+s_n;
    macros += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}"+s_n;

    // iimPlay added before calling iimGetExtract
    macrosrun = iimPlay(macros);
    // pull all extracted values and split the string
    var extracted = iimGetExtract().split(/\[EXTRACT\]/);
    getExtract = parseInt(extracted[0]);
    col5 = extracted[1];
    col6 = extracted[2];
    col7 = extracted[3];

    macros = "CODE:";
    if (getExtract === 1) {
        macros += "URL GOTO=" + col5 +s_n;
    } else if (getExtract  === 2) {
        macros += "URL GOTO=" + col6 +s_n;
    } else if (getExtract  === 3) {
        macros += "URL GOTO=" + col7 +s_n;
    }
    macros += "WAIT SECONDS=1"+s_n;
    macrosrun = iimPlay(macros);
}
```